# send file to google drive or other online store from my server

Tags: backup, google-cloud-storage, online-storage

I am using a shared host. No root access. I want to transfer files between the host and any online storage. The target is to take online backup and restore files from storage to host directly without download/upload. Kindly suggest me some way.

Answer (score 0):

Mover.io is an online service that helps you easily transfer files and folders from one cloud storage service to another. The service works on a freemium model – you can transfer up to 10 GB of data for free and then pay $1 per extra GB of transfer.

Mover has connectors for all popular cloud storage providers. You may copy files from your Google Drive to Dropbox, from SkyDrive to Box or even from your old Google account to the new one. They also support FTP allowing you to directly transfer files from Google Drive or Dropbox to your FTP server, over the cloud.

Comment: I need two way transfer. My FTP to storage and reverse. Is it supported?